# Proof Structural Induction on IntSet union

Tags: scala, induction

Assume you have the following definition:

```
abstract class IntSet {
  def incl(x: Int): IntSet    
  def contains(x: Int): Boolean    
  def union(other: IntSet): IntSet
}

case class NonEmpty(elem: Int, left: IntSet, right: IntSet) extends IntSet {
  def incl(x: Int) =
    if (x < elem) NonEmpty(elem, left incl x, right)
    else if (x > elem) NonEmpty(elem, left, right incl x)
    else this

  def contains(x: Int) =
    if (x < elem) left contains x
    else if (x > elem) right contains x
    else true

  def union(other: IntSet) = (left union (right union other)) incl elem
}

object Empty extends IntSet {
  def incl(x: Int) = NonEmpty(x, Empty, Empty)    
  def contains(x: Int) = false    
  def union(other: IntSet) = other
}
```

and the following proposition has to be proven:

```
(xs union ys) contains x = xs contains x || ys contains x
```

From here I deduce two base cases. xs = Empty and ys = Empty. It is the second base case where I got stuck because of the following reasoning:

```
// substituting ys = Empty
 (xs union Empty) contains x = xs contains x || Empty contains x
// RHS:
 xs contains x || false
 xs contains x
// LHS:
 ((left union (right union Empty)) incl elem) contains x // By definition of NonEmpty.union
```

How can I reduce the LHS to xs contains x? Do I have to do another Induction Hypothesis on xs union Empty = xs and if so, how can that be used to the expression?

Answer (score 2):

To Prove:

`(xs union ys) contains x = xs contains x || ys contains x`

Given:

1. Definitions above
2. `Empty contains x = false`
3. `(s incl x) contains x = true`
4. `(s incl y) contains x = s contains x ; if x != y`

> Induction Step and Structural Proof using xs only, not ys, please refer to the original problem

---

Case I:

`if xs = Empty`
  Left Hand Side:
  `(Empty union ys) contains x`
  `= ys contains x                => Definition of Empty union other`

Right Hand Side:
  `Empty contains x || ys contains x`
  `= false || ys contains x    => Definition of Empty contains x`
  `= ys contains x             => Truth table of OR ( false OR true = true, false OR false = false)`

  Left Hand Side = Right Hand Side hence Induction step proved, the statement is true for all subtrees

---

Case II:
  `if (xs is NonEmpty(z, l, r) and z = x)`
  Left Hand Side:
  `(NonEmpty(x, l, r) union ys) contains x`
  `= ((l union(r union ys)) incl x) contains x       => From definition of union on NonEmpty`
  `= true                                            => from (3) above  (s incl x) contains x = true`

  Right Hand Side: 
  `xs contains x || ys contains x`
  `= NonEmpty(x, l, r) contains x || ys contains x   => From definition of xs`
  `= true || ys contains x                           => From definition of contains on NonEmpty`
  `= true                                            => Truth table of OR (true OR false = true, true OR true = true)`

 Left Hand Side = Right Hand Side

---

Case III:
  `if ( xs is NonEmpty(z, l, r) and z < x )`
  Left Hand Side:
  `(NonEmpty(z, l, r) union ys) contains x`
  `= (l union(r union ys) incl z) contains x    => From definition of union`
  `= (l union(r union ys)) contains x           => From (4) above (s incl x) contains y = s contains y; if x != y`
  `= (l contains x || (r union ys) contains x)  => From induction step, the statement is true for all subtrees`
  `= (l contains x || r contains x || ys contains x) => From induction step, the statement is true for all subtrees`
  `= r contains x || ys contains x              => since z < x, definition of contains (l contains x) returns false`

  Right Hand Side:
  `(if z < x)`
  `NonEmpty(z, l, r) contains x || ys contains x`
  `= r contains x || ys contains x              => definition of contains,`

  Left Hand Side = Right Hand Side,

---

The case `if ( xs is NonEmpty(z, l, r) and z > x )` is analogous to Case III above
  Hence proved